# laravel 4 date format mysql

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, date-format

I am new in Laravel 4 & php.

Is there a way to display 2013-05-30 10:26:39 to 30-May-2013?

My code is

```
$test2 = DB::select('select stringhex, string, testdate from aatest');
```

Thanks.

chankl78

Comment: You can use PHP's `DateTime` class or `Carbon` that comes bundled with L4.

Comment: Do u have any site showing the example for carbon?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes I do. It's called google and you ask it something like "PHP CARBON" which gives you github repository with detailed instructions.

Comment: Thanks!!.. I have try Laravel 4 Carbon in google.. No wonder I do not see what I seeing now..

Thanks for your help.